# Почему gulp не собирает в одну папку?

Tags: gulp

Всем добрый день.
Подскажите, как собрать файлы и каталоги из двух папок в одну, а затем ее заархивировать?

Структура и глубина папок примерно такая, даже глубже:

```
/files
    /folder
        /folder
            /folder
                /file
        /file
        /file
    /folder
        /file
        /file
        /file
    /file

/src
    /folder
        /file
        /file
        /file
    /folder
        /file
    /file
```

Сейчас, почему-то, у меня собираются все файлы **в один текстовый документ**, а не создает папку объединив все содержимое. Соответственно, в архиве тоже только 1 файл ( Подскажите, как это исправить?

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    zip = require('gulp-zip'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify');

...

...

gulp.task('archive', () => {
  return gulp.src(['./files/**/*.*', './src/**/*.*'])
    .pipe(concat('finally'))
    .pipe(rename('./finally v.4'))
    .pipe(zip('./finally v4.xx.zip')) // xx - изменяется вручную здесь
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(notify('Completed!'));
});
```

Comment: В заголовке вы спрашиваете почему НЕ собирается один файл. В вопросе - почему СОБИРАЕТСЯ один файл. Чего вы хотите достичь? Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: подправил, прошу прощения, если не четко сформулировал задачу. Мне нужно объединить папки и их файлы в одну папку, чтобы ее потом заархивировать. Но таск не срабатывает и собирает все содержимое папок и файлов в один текстовый документ.

Comment: Так и работает `gulp-concat`

Comment: это да, но для сбора папок он не работает? подскажите, пожалуйста, чем тогда собирать папки?

Comment: Вы хотите собрать файлы в одну папку без сохранения относительных путей? Или просто заархивировать src и files?

Comment: структура вложенности должна сохраняться после объединения

Comment: Чем не устроил обычный архиватор?

Comment: Попробуйте для начала просто убрать cтроку с .pipe(concat (и rename, соответственно)

Comment: убрал, стало лучше, но все равно не собирает вложенные папки (

Comment: кажется получилось, спасибо всем большое!

Comment: @andrejsharapov будет хорошим тоном добавить к своему вопросу ответ с найденым решением)

Comment: да вот, как раз пытаюсь найти кнопку поднять репутацию или хотя бы спасибку. но, кажется, я слепой)

Comment: @andrejsharapov, Потому что у меня не ответ, а комментарий. Напишите свой ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Помог комментарий [vp_arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth) -"Попробуйте для начала просто убрать cтроку с .pipe(concat (и rename, соответственно)". Убрал, все заработало.